# Cannot tell if cyph is private for messaging

Tags: privacy, instant-messaging

I'm looking for a completely private desktop messaging and i'm not a programmer so i cannot understand their github https://github.com/cyph/cyph

does this look safe to you guys?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their [FAQ](https://www.cyph.com/faq) says:

> What data do you track?
>
> Currently, we only track numbers of: cyph
>   sessions, messages, timeouts, voice/video calls, file transfers,
>   signups, cyphertext UI views, help UI views, and calls to our API.

So - **no**. That's the opposite of "private".

Comment: wow, I obviously didn't see that...what on earth is the point then?  Thank you

Comment: @holly it still _could_ be strong crypto, but the surrounding circumstances will at least cancel out privacy.

Comment: There is no such thing as completely private - but look at Signal from Whisper systems, which comes  close.